# Bash script to make i3 lock activate a timeout of 10 seconds to power down the locked screen

Tags: bash, i3, screen-lock

I have tried to make a script that takes a screenshot of current screen, blur it and set it as background of i3 lock screen.In addition I want to activate a timeout of 10 seconds to power down the locked screen.I linked this script with keybinding for i3 lock but the 10 seconds timeout feature is running without i3 lock as well, my screen's power goes down after every 10 seconds of inactivity.
Here is my script:

````
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                       
img='ss.png'                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                       
scrot "$img"                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                       
convert $img -blur 2,5 $img                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                       
i3lock -i $img                                                                                                                                                         
rm $img                                                                                                                                                                
xset dpms 0 0 10  ```
````

Comment: Fun, but I don't understand what's you'r request

Comment: Basically the last line in script "xset dpms 0 0 10 " enables timeout of 10 seconds for always but I want it only on the i3lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of that `xset` line, you can write something like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

img='ss.png'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
scrot "$img"                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                       
convert "$img" -blur 2,5 "$img"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
i3lock -i "$img"                                                                                                                                                         
rm -f -- "$img"

has_set_dpms=false
while :; do
  if pgrep i3lock >/dev/null; then
    if [ "$has_set_dpms" != true ]; then
      xset dpms 0 0 10
    fi
    has_set_dpms=true
  else
     # Once the process i3lock cannot be found, we turn off DPMS, or
     # you can reset it to what it was before
    xset -dpms
    exit
  fi

  sleep 5
done
```

Essentially, it just loops, checking if i3lock is on. If it is (we just launched it), then we do the `xset` (and use the `has_set_dpms` variable to make sure we only call `xset` once in the while loop).

Once the i3lock process does not exist, then we reset the `dpms` with xset and exit.

Also I thought that `i3lock -i "$img"` would need to have an `&` at the end of the line, but I suppose not...